# How to resolve the jest-haste-map error in react-native?

Tags: react-native

Seen in my Metro Bundler console output:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jest-haste-map'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:/Reat Native demo/kindbase-foodli-app-935bb0d21eae/
```

node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/index.js:19:22)

I make a new project. But I run the `react-native run-android` and the issue still persists?

Answer (score 16):

Try to uninstall react-native from `node_module` folder using command

```
npm uninstall react-native
```

and then re-install that module using command

```
npm install react-native
```

And run your app.

Answer (score 1):

open the file `rn-cli.config.js` and change it to the following :)

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist()
  }
};
```

Comment: where can i find this file?

Comment: You have to create the file.

Answer (score 1):

I reported this on the GitHub repo https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21146

I had to

`rm -rf node_modules
npm install`

to make it work